# Data preprocessing for dynamic linear regression

Tags: time-series, state-space-models, time-varying-covariate, dynamic-regression

In DLM, what kind of preprocessing should be done before fitting the model?

$$Y_t = \beta_t'X_t+\epsilon_t$$
$$\beta_t = \beta_{t-1}+\eta_t$$

1. Should I transform both $Y$ and $X$ into stationary time series? e.g. log, difference of log, etc.
2. Should I centered and standardize $X$ like in Lasso/Ridge regression? If yes, should I do it variable-wise or time-wise?
3. I think the any transformation will have an impact on the signal/noise ratio, does it matter? Because I think a high signal/noise ratio makes the estimation easier in state space model.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi: it's a state space model so you don't even stationarity. I would just leave as is and estimate. key thing is how stable $\beta$ is. If it's flying all over the place, that might be a sign that the model could be improved. note that you need the variances of $\epsilon_t$ and $\eta_t$  before you can run KF  which I assume you estimate in some manner ?

Comment: The variances of $\eta_t$ and $\epsilon_t$ can be estimated by combining KF and EM algorithm. But I think the estimated variance is actually impacted by the scale of $X_t$, like if $X_t$ is in km or miles, the variance can be different. And in SSM, I think a high $\frac{\sigma_\eta}{\sigma_\epsilon}$ leads to a more stable estimation.

Comment: Hi: I can't say for sure but I don't think the units you use should matter ? Also,  note that you can estimate the variances before the KF update by using the prediction error decomposition  in Andrew Harvey blue book. I think the title is "kalman filter and structural models". You can also estimate them by KF-EM but my limited understanding of the latter leads me to believe  that prediction error decomposition is easier. Hopefully others can chime in because I don't feel too confident giving advice on either  A) standardizing or B) usefuleness of using EM instead of prediction error decomp.

Comment: I'll check out prediction error decomposition. Can you please give the name of the book? I found he wrote 4 books about SSM. Thank you, mlofton!

Comment: It's terse and compact ( each page is like 5 pages if someone else wrote them )  which is his general style. I hated it when I read it 20 years ago. Now I glance at it once in a while and realize how good it is. https://www.amazon.com/Forecasting-Structural-Models-Kalman-Filter-ebook/dp/B00HWWPIGA/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=andrew+harvey+structural+models&qid=1585157824&sr=8-1&swrs=7C2225E2F00D4627379AF974B888104E  Note that his other books are very good also ( same description applies ) but they are not really focused on KF-SSM.